# How to solve $(x^2 + 2xy)y' = 2(xy + y^2)$, with $y(1) = 1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've just started learning differential equations(so far I've learnt about separate variables and homogeneous equations) and I'm trying to solve an exercise that is listed as an example for a homogeneous equations. I substituted $\cfrac yx$ for $u$ and after I integrated the equation I still can't get the value of $u$. 
This is the exercise:

$(x^2  + 2xy)y' = 2(xy + y^2)$

$y(1) = 1$

$y' = 2(xy+y^2)/(x^2 + 2xy)$

$\cfrac yx = u => y = xu $

$u +xu' = 2(u + u^2)/(1+2u) $

$xu' = u/(1+2u)$

$u' = u/((1+2u)x)$

Knowing that u' = du/dx

$(1 + 2u)/u du = 1/x dx$

After integration I got the following:

$\ln(|u|) + 2u = \ln(|x|) + c$

$y(1) = 2 => c = \ln2 + 4$

I may have messed up somewhere. What is the easiest way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you think you "messed up somewhere"? Do you know the answer? It isn't the one you got...or what?

Comment: You might want to show the details of your computations to reach $\ln(|u|) + 2u = \ln(|x|) + c$.

Comment: This equation is (at least in my lecture notes' standard) not homogeneous since terms before $y'$ and terms in RHS are polynomials with different degrees

Comment: Oops, I wrote x instead of 2 somewhere. Sorry, I changed it now.

Comment: the title says $y(1) =1$ not 2

Comment: I don't see any problems, except for 2 different values listed for $y(1)$.  And I can't think of any easier way to solve it.

Answer (score -1):

$$(x^2  + 2xy)y' = 2(xy + y^2)$$
I cannot see an easier way that what you did. Your solution $\quad \ln|u|+2u=\ln|x|+c\quad$ is correct.

And with condition $y(1)=1\quad\implies\quad c=2\quad\implies\quad ue^{2u}=e^2x$

Nevertheless it is possible to go a bit further, thanks to the Lambert W function : http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

$$2ue^{2u}=2e^2x \quad\implies\quad 2u=W\left(2e^2x  \right)\quad\implies\quad u=\frac12\: W\left(2e^2x  \right)$$
$$y(x)=\frac{x}{2}\: W\left(2e^2x  \right)$$

Comment: I am curious to know why someone down voted.  I don't care about the $-1$ since I have so much score that I don't know what to do with.  Can the anonymous say what is so bad in my answer. This would allow to improve future answers. After strictly answering to the question, is it prohibited to give additional relevant information which are likely to be of interest to more people ?